# How to clear tomcat auto created copy (cache) of Dspace

Tags: jsp, caching, debian, tomcat6, dspace

Here is one of my experiences I want to share, regarding Debian Linux and Dspace.

After working a day on Dspace and its cache directory in Tomcat, I realized that there is a cache directory of Dspace JSP pages. If you want modified JSP pages (in the installation directory of Dspace) to take affect, you should delete their cache in the following directory:

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost
```

For example, if you want to see new modified `jspui/display-item.jsp` in the browser, you should first delete `/var/lib/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/jspui` directory by:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/jspui
```

Answer (score 2):

try "mvn cleanpackage" it should delete cache in the directory

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost/_
```